# Confusion in a code

Tags: java, set

```
import java.util.*;
class KeyMaster {
  public int i;
  public KeyMaster(int i) { 
    this.i = i; 
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return i == ((KeyMaster)o).i; 
  }
  public int hashCode() { 
    return i; 
  }
}
public class MapIt {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Set<KeyMaster> set = new HashSet<KeyMaster>();
   KeyMaster k1 = new KeyMaster(1);
   KeyMaster k2 = new KeyMaster(2);
   set.add(k1); set.add(k1);
   set.add(k2); set.add(k2);
   System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
   k2.i = 1;
   System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
   set.remove(k1);
   System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
   set.remove(k2);
   System.out.print(set.size());
   }
}
```

confusion about the output
I'm trying to remove element from set the output is still

```
2
2
1
1
```

But expected output is

```
2
2
1
0
```

Comment: ..will you please elaborate your answer

Comment: Both methods are overriding in keymaster class.

Comment: this is a object of Object class which is used as a parameter in equals method... sorry for inconvinence.....

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  The problem is the formatting.  Some of the lines of code were way over to the right and were invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to understand how does `HashSet` work.
When you do:

```
KeyMaster k = new KeyMaster(1);
set.add(k);
```

`HashSet` get hash code of `k` object, and associate this hash code with object. In this case `k` will be associated with `1`.

Now you're changing `k` value by

```
 k.i = 2;
```

Value of `k` object changed, but in `HashSet` this object still associated with `1`, because `HashSet` already remember previous hash code.

So, when you trying remove `k` from `HashSet`

```
set.remove(k);
```

`HashSet` will get hash code of `k`. As you know hash code is changed, and it will be `2`, but in `HashSet` our object still associated with hash code `1`. That's why `HashSet` can not find and remove this object.

Actually, it's bad practice to change hash code after object has added to HashSet.

Comment: "bad practice" is an understatement.  It makes your program _incorrect_, period.

Answer (score 2):

When `k2.i = 1;` and to perform after the `set.remove(k2);` will try to eliminate the element of value 1 and no 2, so the final size will always 1.

Comment: If you want to end the size of the set is 0, you need to delete the item with value 2. But when you do: `k2.i = 1` will try to remove the item with value 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

> the output is still 2 2 1 1

You are overriding both `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

---

First `Sysout` prints the size `2`, contains two items.

Second `Sysout` prints the size `2`, not removing any item from the set.

Third `Sysout` prints the size `1`, removing `k1` already exists with value `1`.

Fourth `Sysout` prints the size `1`, removing `k2` with `k2.i = 1` which does not exists.

---

**EDIT:**

Try to remove `k2` with `k2.i = 2;`, since it exists. Then you will see the  expected output is `2 2 1 0`.

Comment: that means in second sysout it should print size 3 because there are three object k1.i=1, k2.i=2, k2.i=1

Comment: does changing the value of attributes of any object in set creates new copy of object in set

Comment: @AmanGupta Changing the value of an attribute of an object does nothing else, except to change the value of that attribute.  It won't cause a new object to be created.  It won't cause a hash that contains the object to be fixed up.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashSet` (or `HashMap`) is organized as an array of "buckets" where each bucket contains a collection of values.  When you an object to the hash, it will compute the hash code H, determine the bucket number from H (usually H mod some-number), and put the object in that bucket.

Say the hash code is 1 and the object gets put in bucket 1.  Now suppose you do something, like changing `k2.i`, that changes the value of the hash code.  *This does not cause the object to be moved to a different bucket.*  (It can't, since there's no way to set up a "trigger" on a field assignment that would cause the `HashSet` to reevaluate the hash code.)  Now, when you try to do an operation, the `HashSet` class will compute the new hash code, but the object is now in the wrong bucket.  So the class won't find the object.

Basically, changing an object in a way that changes the hash code will totally screw up any `HashSet` or `HashMap` that the object belongs to.  **Never do that.**